# Windows 8 lags after shutdown from power button

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, lag

On Windows 8, every time when the power cuts off or when I turn off the PC from the power button (5sec), the PC lags severely after the restart, and I notice the `system` process is using a high amount of CPU power (60-80%).

And to get it back to its normal state, I have to shut it down from the `Shut down` button, and then open it again.

I'm guessing it's getting lags, because when I open it again it tries to load the old session, and something keeps hanging.

The battery doesn't work anymore, so when I/someone accidentally removes the wire, then I have to wait for like 5min to use it again

Why is this happening, and what can i do to prevent it?

Comment: Why are you closing the PC down that way at all? Does start -> shutdown not work?

Comment: no, it does work, but i have a laptop, but the battery dosnt work anymore, so when I/someone accidentally removes the wire, then i have to wait for like 5min to use it again ..

Comment: Are you saying if you close it properly then this issue does not occur

Comment: @DaveRook exactly.

Comment: You need to copy the comments into your post - as you can see from other people, your question has caused confusion

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is what some people call a "hard shutdown" which is NOT good for your laptop. To solve that, just simply Ctr+Alt+Del-->shutdown.

I too have windows 8 and it's obviously your computer build because I never experience that problem even when I have done hard shutdowns before

Comment: Please read the other comments.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Considering that the actual question is "Why is this happening, and what can i do to prevent it?", I do think this answers (most) of the question.  It's happening because the the op is doing a hard-shutdown, and it can be prevented by shutting down normally.  I experience similar delays after a hard shutdown.  I assume the PC is doing some kind of fsck or something.

Comment: How does it solve it @jimtut - the last paragraph states benimen has never experienced it. The first is a work around but as the OP states, the issue could be when the cable is knocked out since the OP doesn't have a battery. This isn't an answer, at best, a work around

Comment: The problem is that his computer probably cannot handle a hard shutdown that well, my computer however, can, although I choose to not perform a hard shutdown because there is still a chance that my computer could experience the lag as well. My point is that probably because the user does a hard shutdown so often that his (or her) computer probably cannot handle it.

Comment: When i had w windows 7, this never happened ... this never happened also on my old xp machine.

Comment: Then it's probably both a combination of both your computer and Windows 8 on your computer. If it isn't that then you might want to update to Windows 8.1

Comment: @Dave Rook, ok, I agree it's a workaround ("Doctor, it hurts when I do this"...), and not a real solution.  I guess a real "solution" would be do disable the fsck/cleanup that Windows is doing, but I don't recommend skipping something like that after what is basically a crash.

Comment: @benimen, I have 8.1, and it happens to me when I do a hard shutdown.

Comment: @jimtut how can i disable the fsck/cleanup ?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643

Comment: @jimtut didnt help ..